# CSS Transition of fading out but some space still remains in the place of the element

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I've got a list of divs vertically arranged and I'm trying to make a certain element fade out when a button is clicked. As the contents become invisible, I also need to make its height and width 0 in order to free the space. If I do all the transitions at once, the div will change height and width and the text stretches weirdly before it becomes invisible. My attempt to fix it was to add a delay on the height/width transitions, which seems to work, but in the place where the div was, some space still remains, like a margin. I have tried to also transition the margin/padding to 0, but it doesn't do anything.

```
.list-element
    background-color: #E7E9EB;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
```

I am using React and I am dynamically adding the following class to the div on the button press.

```
.list-element-approved
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    transition: height 0.1s 1s, width 0.1s 1s, margin 0.5s 1s, padding 0.5s 1s, opacity 0.5s;
```

[image: This is after removing the second element from the list]

What is the cause of the space that's left behind after the transition? How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because although you've made the approved list element invisible by setting its height to zero, it's still there. The surrounding visible list elements have a margin of 20 pixels *to their neighbours*, and the invisible neighbour is still there. Therefore, the total margin between two visible list items with an invisible list item between them is 40 pixels.

Here's how you can fix this:

```css
.list-element-approved {
  ...
  margin: 0 0 -20px 0;
  ...
}
```

Alternatively, you'd have to remove the approved list item entirely, but that would throw your transition effect off.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the issue. For some reason, it only required -10px, as for -20px was getting them glued together with no space at all.

Comment: It has to do with margin collapsing, when you remove the elements height and margin, the margin of the one before it and the one after collapse with it because it's not completely removed, which makes the total count of the space `40px` because each have `20px`